# Number of tuples that are far from each other

Tags: combinatorics

Consider all $n$-tuples $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ with $a_i \in \{0,\dots,n-1\}$.

Two tuples $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are said to be close to each other if $\mathbf{y} \leq \mathbf{x} \leq 2\mathbf{y}$ or $\mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{y} \leq 2\mathbf{x}$.  Here scalar multiplication and comparison over tuples is performed elementwise.

> What is the size of the largest set of $n$-tuples $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ with $a_i \in \{0,\dots,n-1\}$ such that no pair of tuples are close to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an inspiration, note that any two tuples that have different sets of $0$ entries are far from each other.  We can then separate the tuples into $2^n$ sets with each set having a unique set of zero entries.  I then thought to focus on a set with only one non-zero entry.  It seems obvious that you want the entries you use to be as small as possible as they will exclude less other tuples.  We will have one tuple with a $1$ in this place and cannot have one with $2$.  We can then have one with $3$, one with $7$, one with each $2^k-1$ that is less than $n$.  All this indicates that we have $1+\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor$ distinct choices for each entry in the tuple, giving $\left(1+\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor\right)^n$ tuples that are far from each other.  I don't think this is a solid proof that one can't do better, but it is solid that you can do this well.

Comment: Thank you. Do you suspect this is optimal?

Comment: Yes, I think so.